# How do I connect to password protected servers in nautilus 3.6?

Tags: server, nautilus, android

I am trying to manage my android device with [DavDrive Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.fun2code.android.lite.webdrive&hl=en), which hosts a local file server. The "Connect to server" dialog box in nautilus 3.6 doesn't have the option to type a username and password. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried: `user:password@ip.address`?

Comment: Already tried that, didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple solution but did you **try adding a trailing slash to the end of the server location**? (ex. `davs://server.location.com:0000/` instead of `davs://server.location.com:0000`)

I couldn't connect to my FTP server from Nautilus 3.6 until I added the trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

If you type the address directly if it requires authentication it will ask for them.
Example that I used and had a request of information is ssh://ip.address
[image: login for remote]

Comment: Doesn't work. It might be a bug with the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the port number at the end.

ssh://ip.address:port

Example
  ssh://192.168.0.1:22

and it will ask you the username and password.

I tried it and it worked.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Already fixed it, just forgot to mark it as the answer.